# How to install hadolint on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dockerfile, lint

I am new to ubuntu and installed it 3 days ago.

I tried many steps as told in https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/

But It still tells : 
`hadolint: command not found`

Refer to https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/ for hadolint installation

I managed to install hadolint in windows but , can't install on linux

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This code works and installs the prebuilt binary file :

`wget -O /bin/hadolint https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/releases/download/v2.10.0/hadolint-Linux-x86_64`

I didn't know these basic commands since I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: Also it will be needed to run `chmod +x /bin/hadolint`.

Comment: Awesome!!! This worked for me. I am using WSL 2. And just as @MatheusMaximo said, run `chmod +x /bin/hadolint` after running `wget -O /bin/hadolint https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/releases/download/v1.16.3/hadolint-Linux-x86_64`.