# Can't install hadolint on Ubuntu with WSL 2

Tags: linux, docker, installation, devops

I'm trying to install hadolint to use with docker on a Ubuntu app for Windows with WSL.

Heres how I installed:

```
wget -O /bin/hadolint https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/releases/download/v1.16.3/hadolint-Linux-x86_64
```

and when I ran (on a directory with an Dockerfile):

```
sudo make lint Dockerfile
```

and here's the error I'm getting:

```
# See local hadolint install instructions:   https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint
# This is linter for Dockerfiles
hadolint Dockerfile
make: execvp: hadolint: Permission denied
Makefile:24: recipe for target 'lint' failed
make: *** [lint] Error 127enter code here
```

I new at Linux and I don't know if there's enough information to help me solve this.

Here's some link's I've looked up.

> [How to install hadolint on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62369711/how-to-install-hadolint-on-ubuntu)

> https://github.com/LIMXTEC/BitCore/issues/26

> https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint

And none of them helped me to solve.

Comment: What permissions does the file have?

Comment: Do you mean the Dockerfile?

Comment: No, the `hadolint`

Comment: I don't know how to verify this, but I'm admin.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the local binary, all you need to do is to grant it the execution permission:

```
chmod +x /bin/hadolint
```

Hence you are in the Docker business anyway, you can alternatively use a `hadolint` container to get the job done:

```
docker run --rm -i hadolint/hadolint < Dockerfile
```

where `Dockerfile` is the file you want to lint.

Comment: Both solution didn't work. The first one gave me the same error as before. And the second one gave me this 

docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.

Comment: For the first solution I simply downloaded the binary using the `wget` that you provided, the I added execution permissions and it just worked. Nothing special.

Comment: The second option assumes that you have docker installed and that the daemon is running. Is it? `systemctl status docker`. If it is not running: `systemctl start docker` to star it